# Why does speed of DC motor increase when flux is reduced?

Tags: dc-motor, speed, flux

I understand that from KVL

e = v -IaRa e=k(flux)speed

speed=(constant)*(V-IaRa)/flux

But physically what causes the speed to increase? What force causes the rotor to accelerate? In fact, physically, the rotor is moving because of field flux interacting with armature current's flux. So physically if I reduce one flux, the speed must reduce, since I have reduced the cause of motion as Toque is also depended on Flux.(F=Bil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instant flux is reduced, the back emf reduces and this causes the armature to increase current. More current means a higher driving torque and this accelerates the armature to run at a higher speed until the speed equation is in balance again.

If there is a significant mechanical load this may not happen of course.

Comment: The increase in **I**  in the Equation **F= BIL** affects more than the decrease in B?

Comment: [This](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/14921/en/) website gives the proof that speed is inversely proportional to flux per pole

Comment: Remember that with a DC motor the only thing that determines speed is the balancing of the back-emf with the applied voltage so, if flux drops, the armature speed has to increase in order to produce nearly the same back emf so that motor torque is balanced by the torque required by the mechanical losses to run at that higher speed.